# Dealing with Firebase observers when userID changes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use this function inside an helper class to fetch the trips of a user. It keeps listening for new changes:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class APICardService: NSObject {
    class func fetchTrips(forID userID: String, completion: @escaping ([Trip]) -> Void) {
        let path = "users/\(userID)/trips"
        Database.database().reference().child(path).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            var trips = [Trip]()
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let child = child as? DataSnapshot {
                    if let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                        let trip = Trip(key: child.key, dbValues: dict)
                        trips.append(trip)
                    }
                }
            }
            completion(trips)
        }
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // but what if the userID changes? I have no way to stop the current observer and start a new one
    internal func fetchCards() {
        guard let userID = APIAuthService.getUserID() else { return }
        APICardService.fetchTrips(forID: userID) { trips in
            self.trips = trips.reversed() // show most recent first
            self.addAnnotations(for: trips)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever the user signs out and logs into a new account this observer will still be listening for new value changes in the data but it won't work because the userID changed. How do I deal with this? I could remove the observer somehow but this is complicated because we're inside a separate class and I wouldn't know how to handle that.

Comment: keep the ref. of observer  like `let ref = Database.database().reference()..` when you do logout just remove that

Comment: Thanks @PrashantTukadiya. Would you mind answering with a small code snipped?

Comment: observation 1) I should use a singleton with a static shared instance class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `APICardService` create these global variables

```
static var refHandle:DatabaseHandle?  = nil
static var ref:DatabaseReference? = nil
```

in your Method `func fetchTrips(forID userID: String, completion: @escapin`

assign global variables like this

```
let path = "users/\(userID)/trips"
ref = Database.database().reference().child(path)
refHandle =  ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
```

Now you have the reference of your observer

just add following method in your class

```
class func removeObserverForFetchTrip() {
        if let refHandleValue = refHandle {
            ref?.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandleValue)
        }
}
```

When user logout just call this method

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

As @PrashantTukadiya says.
Try making something like this:

```
struct User {
    var id: String
    ...
}

class UserHolder {
    static var shared: UserHolder = UserHolder() // Singleton

    var currentUser: User? {
        willSet {
            // Remove all the registered firebase handlers associated with the user
            firebaseHandles.forEach({ $0.0.removeObserver(withHandle: $0.1) })
        }
    }

    var firebaseHandles: [(DatabaseReference, UInt)] = []

    // Note: Try to add all the firebase handles you register to "firebaseHandles"
    //   array. The more adequate solution is to make this class register
    //   the listeners, not all other classes.
}
```